# Set grid layout in video call UI (web SDK)

Tags: agora.io, videochat, video-conferencing, agora-web-sdk-ng

I want to achieve grid layout in my video call application which I am building with Agora's web SDK.
I was browsing the docs , but I couldn't get an help on how to achieve grid layout in video conferencing.
The best fit and grid layouts are only available in cloud recording APIs.

Any previous reference or github repo where it is implemented would also work.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The Agora Web SDK provides a library for video streaming, it does not enforce a UI. Building the UI is your task. That being said, Agora makes its very easy to add video chat to your application.

In your case you can build a grid layout using CSS grid or any framework of your choosing. To connect Agora to your Grid layout you would use the `stream-published` event to create a new grid element, and *subscribe* to the new stream. Once the `subscribe()` promise resolves, use the video track's `.play()` method to play the video on a specific DOM element

```js
client.on("user-published", async (user, mediaType) => {
  // Initiate the subscription
  await client.subscribe(user, mediaType);

  // If the subscribed track is an audio track
  if (mediaType === "audio") {
    const audioTrack = user.audioTrack;
    // Play the audio
    audioTrack.play();
  } else {
    const videoTrack = user.videoTrack;
    // Play the video the given DOM_ELEMENT
    videoTrack.play(DOM_ELEMENT);
  }
});
```